# Install Driver WIFI Realtek 8821ce on a new Ubuntu 18.02 PC without internet connection (Command Make not installed)

Tags: drivers, realtek

I want to Install WIFI Driver Realtek 8821ce on my new Ubuntu 18.02 PC without internet connection (Command Make not installed) so that my pc detects wifi networks

Thank !

Comment: Do you have or can you download again the original install DVD or USB? Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: i don't undernstand, probably not

Comment: Please check your release; there was no 2018.February (18.02) release of Ubuntu, so you'll mean 18.04 or 18.10 (April or October release).  The `build-essential` is not installed by default, so you need to install it (from install media which is reason for prior comment), or downloaded & installed via another usb-thumb-drive.

Comment: 18.02, and i tried to install build essential manually from a connected PC, also Make command is not installed and couldn't install it manually !

Comment: @Nmath OP has no internet connection.